# Reset Serial Numbers in columns on the basis of some conditions in Oracle 11g Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am facing a challenge to meet a (custom) business requirement in which values of two columns to be recalculated on the basis of some predefined rules. Is there any way to achieve the same by using query (without using PL/SQL)?

Let me try to explain in three steps (seeking help for step 3 only):

Step 1: Fetch Raw data as shown in following table: (image and CSV for copy paste)

[image]

```
CUSTOMER_ID,STATEMENT_NUMBER,STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER,NEW_LINES
13528,375,51,8
13528,375,51,10
13528,375,51,12
13528,375,51,6
13528,375,51,11
13528,375,51,4
13528,375,51,2
13528,375,51,8
13528,375,51,10
13528,375,51,10
13528,375,51,18
13528,375,51,20
13528,375,51,16
13528,375,51,10
13528,375,51,8
```

Step 2: Add/accumulate values of "NEW_LINES" in "STATEMENT_LINE_NUMB" as shown in following table: (image and CSV for copy paste)

[image]

```
CUSTOMER_ID,STATEMENT_NUMBER,STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER,NEW_LINES
13528,375,59,8
13528,375,69,10
13528,375,81,12
13528,375,87,6
13528,375,98,11
13528,375,102,4
13528,375,104,2
13528,375,112,8
13528,375,122,10
13528,375,132,10
13528,375,150,18
13528,375,170,20
13528,375,186,16
13528,375,196,10
13528,375,204,8
```

Step 3: After adding "NEW_LINES" IN "STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBERS", if the value in column "STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER" >= 60 then:

a) Very next record in "STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER" will start with value of "NEW_LINES" and subsequently values of "NEW_LINES" will be added/accumulated

b) From very next record, value of "STATEMENT_NUMBER" will be increased by 1 and next row will carry incremented number till the time value of "STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER" exceeds 60 as shown in following table: (image and CSV for copy paste)

[image]

```
CUSTOMER_ID,STATEMENT_NUMBER,STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER,NEW_LINES
13528,375,59,8
13528,375,69,10
13528,376,12,12
13528,376,18,6
13528,376,29,11
13528,376,33,4
13528,376,35,2
13528,376,43,8
13528,376,53,10
13528,376,63,10
13528,377,18,18
13528,377,38,20
13528,377,54,16
13528,377,64,10
13528,378,8,8
```

Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Too many rules...have you tried something yourself yet?

Comment: Please use text and not images - I think many members will be happy to look at your problem but no one likes to type all that text...

Comment: @KoenLostrie thanks for pointing out it. I have updated question by adding table values as CSV. Please let me know if you need anything else. (Images have been used for better demonstration by highlighting values)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have been using SUM() OVER () to accumulate numbers and LAG() OVER () to pick value of STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER from last row. It works but for first iteration only but when it crosses first 60 then it does not give desired results.

Answer (score 4):

From Oracle 12c, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
WITH ordered_lines (
  CUSTOMER_ID, STATEMENT_NUMBER, STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER, NEW_LINES, RN
) AS (
  -- Order the rows
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY customer_id
           ORDER BY statement_number, statement_line_number, ROWNUM
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
),
ordered_statements (
  CUSTOMER_ID, STATEMENT_NUMBER, NEW_LINES, RN
) AS (
  -- Pivot the statement_line_number into the new_lines column at row 0
  SELECT customer_id, statement_number, statement_line_number, 0
  FROM   ordered_lines
  WHERE  RN = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT customer_id, statement_number, new_lines, rn
  FROM   ordered_lines
),
running_totals (
  CUSTOMER_ID, STATEMENT_NUMBER, STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER, NEW_LINES, RN
) AS (
  -- Split into 60+ row groups and then generate running totals.
  SELECT customer_id,
         statement_number + mno - 1,
         SUM( new_lines ) OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id, mno ORDER BY rn ),
         new_lines,
         RN
  FROM   ordered_statements
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY customer_id
    ORDER     BY rn
    MEASURES
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN ( short_lines* last_lines )
    DEFINE short_lines AS SUM(new_lines) < 60
  )
)
SELECT customer_id, statement_number, statement_line_number, new_lines
FROM   running_totals
WHERE  rn > 0;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CUSTOMER_ID,STATEMENT_NUMBER,STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER,NEW_LINES) AS
SELECT 13528,375,51,8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13528,375,51,8 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | STATEMENT_NUMBER | STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER | NEW_LINES
> ----------: | ---------------: | --------------------: | --------:
>       13528 |              375 |                    59 |         8
>       13528 |              375 |                    69 |        10
>       13528 |              376 |                    12 |        12
>       13528 |              376 |                    18 |         6
>       13528 |              376 |                    29 |        11
>       13528 |              376 |                    33 |         4
>       13528 |              376 |                    35 |         2
>       13528 |              376 |                    43 |         8
>       13528 |              376 |                    53 |        10
>       13528 |              376 |                    63 |        10
>       13528 |              377 |                    18 |        18
>       13528 |              377 |                    38 |        20
>       13528 |              377 |                    54 |        16
>       13528 |              377 |                    64 |        10
>       13528 |              378 |                     8 |         8
> ```

For Oracle 11g, you could use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to iterate over the rows sequentially (it probably won't be as efficient as `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` though):

```sql
WITH ordered_lines (
  CUSTOMER_ID, STATEMENT_NUMBER, STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER, NEW_LINES, RN
) AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY customer_id
           ORDER BY statement_number, statement_line_number, ROWNUM
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
),
ordered_statements (
  CUSTOMER_ID,
  ORIG_STATEMENT_NUMBER,
  NEW_STATEMENT_NUMBER,
  STATEMENT_LINE_NUMBER,
  NEW_LINES,
  RN
) AS (
  SELECT customer_id,
         statement_number,
         statement_number,
         statement_line_number,
         statement_line_number,
         0
  FROM   ordered_lines
  WHERE  RN = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT s.customer_id,
         s.orig_statement_number,
         CASE
         WHEN s.statement_line_number >= 60
         THEN s.new_statement_number + 1
         ELSE s.new_statement_number
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN s.statement_line_number >= 60
         THEN l.new_lines
         ELSE s.statement_line_number + l.new_lines
         END,
         l.new_lines,
         l.rn
  FROM   ordered_statements s
         INNER JOIN ordered_lines l
         ON (
           s.customer_id = l.customer_id
           AND s.orig_statement_number = l.statement_number
           AND s.rn + 1 = l.rn
         )
)
SELECT customer_id,
       new_statement_number AS statement_number,
       statement_line_number,
       new_lines
FROM   ordered_statements
WHERE  rn > 0;
```

A third option is to use the `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       statement_number + offset AS statement_number,
       total_line_number AS statement_line_number,
       new_lines
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY customer_id, statement_number
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (customer_id, statement_number)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (
    statement_line_number AS sln,
    new_lines, 
    0 AS total_line_number,
    0 AS offset
  )
  RULES (
    total_line_number[rn] = CASE
                            WHEN total_line_number[cv(rn)-1] >= 60
                            THEN 0
                            ELSE COALESCE(total_line_number[cv(rn)-1], sln[cv(rn)])
                            END + new_lines[cv(rn)],
    offset[rn]            = CASE
                            WHEN total_line_number[cv(rn)-1] >= 60
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END + COALESCE(offset[cv(rn)-1], 0)
  )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27663cb6b6b4b6ba2f14a3f6442f45b9)*

Comment: Thanks @MT0. This query shows that you have an excellent command writing Oracle's complex query but unfortunately i am using 11g. Do you think we can find other ways to achieve the same result no matter if we have to execute multiple queries one by one.

Comment: @ATTA Added an Oracle 11g query.

Comment: Thanks @MT0 for your great effort again. I executed the query but encountered following error message: ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing
32033. 00000 -  "unsupported column aliasing"
*Cause:    column aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet
*Action:   specify aliasing in defintion subquery and retry
Error at Line: 32 Column: 20

Comment: @ATTA It works on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd6ca1553532745c6596f2025d3da020) on Oracle 11gR2. If you are on Oracle 11gR1 then I do not have any instance which uses that version that I can use to debug the query. I would guess that you need to go from `WITH subqueryname ( aliases ... ) AS ( ...query... )` to `WITH subqueryname AS ( ...query... )` and include the aliases in the query but I cannot test it and I'm not sure that the recursive subquery would be supported.

Comment: I will try as you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: @ATTA Added a 3rd option.

Comment: once again excellent, marvelous work you have done and it worked for me as well for given example. To keep question simple i used example of one customer id only but in case of considering all customers rownumber "rn" will be started from 1 for every customer so my question is, will there be any chance of misscalcuation while using "total_line_number[cv(rn)-1] >= 60"?

Comment: @ATTA The `Model` clause version is using `PARTITION BY (customer_id, statement_number)` different customers & statement number pairs will be in different partitions; its not entirely clear what you think might be miscalculated but if you are asking if totals can get mixed up between customers then, no, they're in different partitions.

Comment: yes you got my question exactly. Thanks again, you are gem of person. I wish i can click up arrow 100 times for your answers but Stackoverflow doesn't allow :) I will apply your given solution on entire data by including other columns what i intentionally did not include to keep question simple and may contact (bother) you again if i encounter any other challenge. Keep your good work up.